# impala-server start java.io.IOException: No FileSystem for scheme: hdfs

Tags: hdfs, impala

When I execute the command *impala-server start*，

> hdfsBuilderConnect(forceNewInstance=0, nn=default, port=0,
>   kerbTicketCachePath=(NULL), userName=(NULL)) error:
>   java.io.IOException: No FileSystem for scheme: hdfs
>           at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.getFileSystemClass(FileSystem.java:2798)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:2809)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.access$200(FileSystem.java:100)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.getInternal(FileSystem.java:2848)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:2830)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:389)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$1.run(FileSystem.java:171)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$1.run(FileSystem.java:168)
>           at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>           at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1807)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:168) Wrote minidump to
>   /var/log/impala/minidumps/impalad/591f69ee-609a-b084-09f1f8ee-7f7bbb62.dmp

Who can help me?

Comment: Looks like the Hadoop client scanned its Java CLASSPATH for directories, then searched these directories for Hadoop config files such as `core-site.xml` and `hdfs-site.xml`, but did not find the address of the HDFS NameNode in there...

Comment: @Samson Scharfrichter ,thanks for the reply，use impala version is 2.8.0，but hadoop version is 2.8.0，impala2.8.0 support hadoop2.6.0，so reported such a problem，but now appear new problem

Comment: F0702 11:14:45.117648   382 impalad-main.cc:64] NoSuchMethodError: setCaching
. Impalad exiting.
*** Check failure stack trace: ***
    @          0x1b61bed  (unknown)
    @          0x1b64516  (unknown)
    @          0x1b6170d  (unknown)
    @          0x1b64fbe  (unknown)
    @           0xb2a27c  (unknown)
    @           0x7d2613  (unknown)
    @       0x3dd7a1ed1d  (unknown)
    @           0x80385d  (unknown)
Wrote minidump to /var/log/impala/minidumps/impalad/4cc67541-2dfc-915d-6cd82382-69a1b473.dmp

Comment: Now you are in the C++ Impala codebase. Good luck.